# fullcalendar create event on click JS

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Hello i would like to know how to create an event on click with Fullcalendar and javascript.

Like on the demo with the "Selectable Dates" https://fullcalendar.io/

Im new in developpement

Thanks

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
    },
   
    
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried pressing the 'Learn more' link? It leads to [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting). You might find your answer [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback).

Answer (score 1):

First, your calendar must have dateClick and/or select properties.

```js
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: ['interactionPlugin', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'moment'],
  views: {...},
  headerToolbar: {...},
  dateClick: function(dateClickInfo) { // Only for a specific date
    // Here you can use the dateClicInfo with your createEvent function
    createEvent(dateClickInfo.dateStr, 'Some event', undefined);
  },
  select: function(selectionInfo) { // Similar to dateClick
    createEvent(selectionInfo.startStr, 'Some event', selectionInfo.endStr);
  }
});
```

Then in your createEvent function you can handle the event creation

```js
const events = [];

function createEvent(startDate, title, endDate) {
  const event = {
    id: 1, // You must use a custom id generator
    title: title,
    start: startDate,
    allDay: endDate ? endDate : true // If there's no end date, the event will be all day of start date
  }

  events.push(event);
}
```

See the event object info https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Comment: Don't forget that `selectable: true` must also be set before selecting will be activated.

Comment: Thank you all i will watch this with attention